# Pandas GroupBy by Multiple Funcs

Tags: pandas

How it can be solved?

```
technologies   = ({
    'Courses':["Spark","PySpark","Hadoop","Python","Pandas","Hadoop","Spark","Python"],
    'Fee' :[22000,25000,23000,24000,26000,25000,25000,22000],
    'Duration':['30days','50days','35days','40days','60days','35days','55days','50days'],
    'Discount':[1000,2300,1000,1200,2500,1300,1400,1600]
                })
df = pd.DataFrame(technologies, columns=['Courses','Fee','Duration','Discount'])
```

Code below give error

```
df.groupby(['Courses']).agg(count_of_duration = ('Duration', 'count'), min,max = ('Fee', ['min', 'max']))
```

> File "", line 1
> df.groupby(['Courses']).agg(count_of_duration = ('Duration', 'count'), min,max = ('Fee', ['min', 'max']))
> ^
> SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

I try to be get result like this but shorter

```
a = df.groupby(['Courses']).agg({'Duration' : 'count','Fee' : ['min', 'max']}).\

rename(columns = {'count' : 'Count', 'min' : 'Minimum', 'max' : 'Maximum'}).reset_index()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "shorter"? More concise code? If you want a MultiIndex as output, that's already quite good.

Comment: Write 'min, max' is not allowed, so how i can change it? I mean more concise code yeah

Comment: I don't think  you can do better than that.

Comment: df.groupby(['Courses']).agg(count_of_duration = ('Duration', 'count'), min,max = ('Fee', ['min', 'max'])). In this code its not allowed write min, max. But i want to get result like ['min', 'max'] = ('Fee', ['min', 'max']) and output should be like a = df.groupby(['Courses']).agg({'Duration' : 'count','Fee' : ['min', 'max']}).\

rename(columns = {'count' : 'Count', 'min' : 'Minimum', 'max' : 'Maximum'}).reset_index() but i dont like to write big code with rename method and try to write concise code

Comment: You can't pass anything else other than valid python names as parameters to `agg` (or strings if using dictionary expansion). I'm afraid what you're looking for is not possible. `df.groupby(['Courses'], as_index=False).agg(count_of_duration=('Duration', 'count'), min=('Fee', 'min'), max=('Fee', 'min'))` is the required format.